# What's the criteria for a close review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed my first review audit, and I'm unclear what I should have done.

I was going through questions that had been nominated for closure based on **Primarily opinion-based**.  The review question, however, was not tagged with that reason (why was I seeing it?).  Instead, it was tagged with **Unclear what you're asking**.

I read the entire question, and, while it wasn't a great question, it *was* clear what was being asked.  Thus I chose to "Leave Open" and was scolded by the review audit system.

As I said, it wasn't a great question, but the person or persons who had nominated it as **Unclear what you're asking** were wrong.  If I had voted to close the question, I'd have been rewarding bad moderations (as well as penalizing a newbie user who was already suffering downvotes).

It seems, as you're going through the review queue, that you're being asked to do two different things:

1. Determine if the question meets one of the criteria for closure, and
2. Determine if others' moderations were appropriate.

For some questions, those two things conflict.  What is the right thing to do in these conflicts?

If the answer is that you should just focus on the question, then I'd suggest that the review queue should not show the reasons why others have voted to close the question.  Showing the reasons biases the reviewer and creates confusion about what the reviewer is expected to do.  (And, from that, it follows that you wouldn't be able to filter close reviews based on the reasons they were nominated for closure.)

Comment: "2.Determine if others' moderations were appropriate." That's definitely not the task. The hints are only for getting you started looking. And anyway, you would see them (or even more) when selecting a close-reason anyway.

Comment: If that's not the task, then I'd argue that the UI should not be showing the reasons the others have nominated the question for closing.  It creates a cognitive dissonance, making it unclear what should be done.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this discussion.  I'm not trying to raise a debate on whether the question should have been closed or not.  It's about meta-moderation and whether the review UI creates ambiguity in the task.

Answer (score 3):

[This one, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8311997)

Let's start with the title.

> How to run a program “for” in Python?

I know that titles suck - and not just in general, but more from an information conveyance standpoint - but this one is especially unclear.  It's likely that they are conflating the `for` keyword with a program, but that doesn't help this question all that much.

Now, to the body:

> I have tried solving the problem AE00 on Spoj and this is leading to me a wrong result.What change should be done in the following code so that it should work?

The phrase "wrong result" and the lack of what that wrong result *is* should be a red flag.  There's not enough information about what the result is or what is should be; all they mention is "AE00 on Spoj".  Suppose that site goes down when someone's looking at this question; how will they ever understand what the context is?

Also, "should work" should also raise a few red flags.  There's no success criteria; that is, nothing in the question indicates a successful resolution to the problem in terms of input.

I'm not saying that the close reason was right - in fact, it should be the "Why isn't this code working?" reason.  But, this is still one of those audit failures that you're going to have to study for a bit.  It's still a very poor question, and should be regarded as such.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "why isn't this code working" is effectively a special case of "unclear".  It's saying that a more specific piece of information is missing (the example to reproduce or the problem statement) whereas "unclear" covers that as well as any other missing or poorly communicated information.  "why isn't this code working' *would* have been better, as it gives the OP more specific information about what's wrong and how to fix it, so I would prefer it, but Unclear isn't *wrong* here; it *does* apply.

Comment: I believe the part you quoted omits the most important bit:  the user wanted to know how to loop over a range of integers up to the square root of n, and he/she showed how they attempted it.  I 100% agree it's not a great question, and, in fact, it now has a score of -6, though it was only -3 when I saw it.  But it is clear what the question is and what they tried.

Comment: By the way, how did you find the question?  I tried using the back button in the browser and I tried searching for it but was unable to retrieve it.

Comment: Your activity history has whatever reviews you performed in it.  It's a public record so it makes finding things like this easier.

Comment: This answer misses the gist of my question:  What should a reviewer do when a closed question is bad but close reason is incorrect?